# Pass by reference primitive types in Swift

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference, primitive-types

I am trying to have a model which shares a value with the objects it contains. In the below example I have a `Model` object, a, which contains a `Struct`, b. I would like them both to have access to a `Bool` which is referenced by variables a and aa. In order to do this, I have wrapped a `Bool` in a `Box` structure.

```
struct Box<Value> {
    var value:Value
}

struct Model {
    var a: Box<Bool>
    var b:B
    struct B {
        var aa:Box<Bool>
    }
}

struct TestView : View {
    @State var model:Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.a.value.description)
            Text(model.b.aa.value.description)

            Button(action: {
                self.model.a.value.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code as such:

```
let box = Box<Bool>(value: true)
let contentView = TestView(model: Model(a: box, b: Model.B(aa: box)))
```

The value in model.b.aa is not updated as I would expect. Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: can you specify what are you trying to achieve , it seems to very complex . May be first you should break it down to simpler solution .

Comment: The essence of the question is how I would share a primitive type between two objects and have updates to the primitive type update in the view

Answer (score -1):

For your purpose, you'd need to wrap the primitive type in a class, and share an instance of that class. There is no raw reference or pointer that can be shared between the structs.

Comment: where would I add "inout"? I do not have any methods in my example.

Comment: Sorry. I mistook that you were dealing with functions. For your purpose, you'd need to wrap the primitive type in a class, and share an instance of that class. There is no raw reference or pointer that can be shared between the structs.

Comment: I see, if I use a class instead of a struct for Box, then the UI no longer updates, is this something to do with how classes work in State property wrappers?